Maximizing $\sum_{i<j} \frac{x_i x_j}{\sum_{k=i}^j x_k}$ over compositions of $m$
I'm interested in the one-parameter family of optimization problems, parametrized by $m \in \mathbf{Z}^+$
$$\max_{n, x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \in \mathbf{Z}^+ \\ x_1+x_2+\cdots + x_n=m} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n  \frac{x_i x_j}{\sum_{k=i}^j x_k}.$$
The search space is all integer compositions of $m$. Coding this quickly, I've managed to show that the solution is the all-ones vector $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{1}_m$ for $m \leq 13$. I would like to prove this is the solution for all $m$. I've tried three approaches, but couldn't get either to work:

Treat the variables as continuous and search for critical points.
The method above after replacing each denominator with a sum of ones, to get a polynomial objective.
Trying to prove that the objective function increases under discrete transformations splitting any variable greater than one. For example, with $m=4$, $(1,3) \mapsto (1,2,1)$ should increase the objective.

I couldn't find a closed form expression for the critical points in approaches 1 and 2, and while approach 3 empirically seems correct, the algebra there is also quite messy.
I would appreciate any help in solving the optimization problem for all $m$, especially if the solution is simple. Thanks.

Can you write out the full version of the expression for $n = 3, 4$? That might provide further insight as to what the calculation could be.  $\quad$ FWIW I do think your "split any variable" idea is right. Just track what the newly introduced fractions are (and that's partly why I asked for $n = 3, 4$).

Below is a proof that for the halved objective function $u(\mathbf{x})$
$$\operatorname{arg max}_{n,x_1,\dots,x_n \in \mathbf{Z}^+ \\ x_1+\dots+x_n=m} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{x_i x_j}{\sum_{k=i}^j x_k} = \mathbf{1}_m.$$
The first step is evaluating the objective at inputs $\mathbf{x}$ ending with a potentially empty all-ones vector
$$u(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_p,\mathbf{1}_{m-\sum_{q=1}^p k_q}) =\\ \sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^p \frac{k_i k_j}{\sum_{r=i}^j k_r} + \sum_{i=1}^p k_i \left( H_{m-\sum_{r=1}^{i-1} k_r} - H_{\sum_{r=i}^p k_r} \right) + \left( m+1-\sum_{r=1}^p k_r \right) H_{ m+1-\sum_{r=1}^p k_r }-1-2m+2 \sum_{r=1}^p k_r ,$$
where $H_x$ denotes the $x$th harmonic number. Next compute the forward difference
$$
\Delta_{k_p}  u(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_p,\mathbf{1}_{m-\sum_{q=1}^p k_q})  = u(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_p+1,\mathbf{1}_{m-1-\sum_{q=1}^p k_q})-u(k_1,k_2,\dots,k_p,\mathbf{1}_{m-\sum_{q=1}^p k_q})=\\
H_{m-\sum_{r=1}^{p-1}k_r}-H_{m-\sum_{r=1}^{p}k_r}-H_{k_p}-k_p\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \frac{ k_i}{\left( \sum_{r=1}^p k_r \right) \left( 1+\sum_{r=1}^p k_r \right) }.
$$
The last term is clearly negative. The combination of of the three harmonic numbers is also negative, as while the positive and negative terms are equal in number ($m-\sum_{r=1}^{p-1} k_r$), some of the negative terms are shifted earlier in the sequence, making them larger.
Using this result iteratively we can prove that $u(\mathbf{1}_m) > u(\mathbf{x})$ for any other input:
$$u(\mathbf{1}_m) = u(1,\mathbf{1}_{m-1}) > u(2,\mathbf{1}_{m-2}) >  u(3,\mathbf{1}_{m-3}) > \dots > u(x_1, \mathbf{1}_{m-x_1}) > \dots > u(x_1,x_2, \mathbf{1}_{m-x_1-x_2}) \\> \dots > u(\mathbf{x}) . $$
I also managed to compute
$$
u(\mathbf{1}_m) = (m+1) H_{m+1}-2 m-1.
$$
